# How to convert a .csv file into a .txt format

Tags: bash, csv, unix

csv file in excel and saved it as .txt and when I count the lines using 
wc -l there is one line less in the .txt format 17768 vs 17769.
1. Is this normal and if so which line is lost in the conversion?
2. What is the easiest way to make this conversion in bash?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can treat .csv as .txt files (open a csv in a text editor, it should be easy to tell)

Comment: A .csv file is already text, whether it's in Excel or not. There is no *conversion to .txt* either needed or possible. We don't have the file to try to find out why there's a one-line difference; you do. You'll need to use a diff utility or open the files and look at them yourself to find the line that is different.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a CSV file is a text file.

Answer (score 1):

`wc -l` count records based on row delimiter (`\n`) most probably your last record do not have row delimiter.

For example `echo` commands add a new line at the end but `printf` won't.

Demo:

```
$echo -e "1\n2" | wc -l
2
$printf "1\n2" |  wc -l
1
$
$echo -e "1\n2" | od -c
0000000   1  \n   2  \n
0000004
$printf "1\n2" |  od -c
0000000   1  \n   2
0000003
$
```

Both printf and echo are print 2 records. But as we don't have row delimiter (`\n` ) at the end of string `wc` is showing only 1 record

```
$echo -e "1\n2"
1
2
$printf "1\n2"
1
2$
```